# Ignoring method in TestNG assert messages

Tags: java, testng

When a test fails with an assert in a TestNG test method it outputs a message containing the method name like so

```
MyTestFixture:49->when_clicking_x_y_happens:49 expected:<Foo...> but was:<Bar...>
```

So far all is good. However, when having asserts in another method than the test method it displays a weird message:

```
MyTestFixture:49->TestHelper.verifyXYZwasDisplayed:49 expected:<Foo...> but was:<Bar...>
```

Here the `verifyXYZwasDisplayed` from the `TestHelper` class is displayed in the message. It would be more helpful if the message contained the test method name instead. Can I somehow annotate this method be ignore when TestNG creates the assert message?

Answer (score 1):

I guess your `TestHelper.verifyXYZwasDisplayed()` method has an `assert*()` in it. Which means the `AssertionError` thrown will point at the line where this assertion is used.

Instead, make it return a boolean which is true if the condition is met, then use:

```
assertTrue(TestHelper.verifyXYZwasDisplayed(blah));
```

Comment: so there is no way to do it? If I do this, then the message gets much worse: "Expected true, but was false". Thats is not so helpful...

Comment: You can customize the error message (second argument). The other solution would be to make a custom assert, but even then the error will be associated to the line in the custom assert, not the method itself

Comment: No, in a regular assert you do not have to specify a message to get the nice "Expected x, but got y" message.

Comment: Which doesn't mean you can't do it, can you?

Comment: well... I can do _that_, but apparently I cannot do what I asked in the question...

Comment: As far as I know, no you can't. The location of the exception is the line/method/file where the exception was thrown. Maybe unwindinw the stacktrace can give you what you want, but I have never tried that.